# Killing fields, about the definition

Tags: differential-geometry

In Peter Petersen, Riemannian Geometry it can be read the definition of Killing Vector Fields, that said, $X$ is a Killing vector field if his local flows act by isometries. I dont know what does mean ''act by isometries''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Act by isomoetries means that if $\phi_t$ is the flows of $X$, $\phi_t^*g=g$ where $g$ is the metric.

$g_x(X,Y)=g_{\phi_{-t}(x)}(d\phi_{-t}(X),d\phi_{-t}(Y))$

Comment: And $\phi_t : M \to M$ is an isometry?

Comment: Yes, this means that $\phi_t$ is an isometry.

Comment: And how can you deduce that $L_X g = 0$?